# MySQL has broke, can not be started: "Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer..."

Tags: mysql, server, debian, mariadb

When attempting to start the mysql server, it returns with exit code 1. I've done this a million times before on this server. **Without messing with the server in the past month**, mysql has suddenly stopped and I can not start it. My error.log:

```
[Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
[Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
[Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
[Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
[Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
[Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
[Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
[Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
[Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
[Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
[Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=591771482442

Everything goes to ruin below this line.

[Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery to ignore this error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
[ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
[Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
[ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
[ERROR] Aborting
```

Until I can start mysql-server, I can not run `mysqldump` nor `mysql -u root`:

```
Got error: 2002: "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")" when trying to connect
```

I'm running mariadb-server 10.1.23-9-deb9u1.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log in place of "Everything goes to ruin below this line."? It is suspicious that the doublewrite buffer recovery, without any indication of its failure, would make InnoDB fail

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work but since the server doesn't work anyway so try this out:

> Rename `logfile0` and `logfile1` and then restart the server.

Before doing anything, make a copy of the entire mysql folder to another location just in case.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was right infront of me:

```
InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery to ignore this error.
```

I set `innodb_force_recovery = 1` after the [mysqld] clause in my `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` (This file may very depending on your OS).

I restarted it and it repaired itself. I later took out the `innodb_force_recovery = 1` and restarted again, it then worked just fine.

What did I learn? Have more faith in "auto-repair" procedures. My expectations were so low for them because of my exposure to Microsoft Windows.

Comment: innodb_force_recovery = 1 ignores corrupt pages. How do you know it has "repaired itself"? Can you access your data?

Comment: @LaurynasBiveinis Yep. Everything is back to normal. No idea, perhaps in the middle of a write a brief power outage?

Comment: Here's the problem: *[Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite buffer...* **is not an error**.  Thus, it doesn't make sense for that line to be followed by *InnoDB: Set innodb_force_recovery to ignore this error.*  Also, `innodb_force_recovery` is not a well-named option.  It essentially makes the recovery process **less cautious, less thorough.**  [*"Only set `innodb_force_recovery` to a value greater than 0 in an emergency situation, so that you can start InnoDB and dump your tables."*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html)

Comment: If you continue to use this server without rebuilding it, be aware that you may simply have caused an error to be ignored.  You may have lost data, you may have latent corruption.  I believe you may have edited out the line that actually tells what went wrong, from the logs.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Noted. Dumping SQL now. Make an answer out of your comments and you've got the points.

Comment: Did you snip anything from that error log? I'd like to understand better what exactly prevented InnoDB from starting, to make the answer as relevant as possible.

Comment: Michael, no. However I did find out that one of my drupal sites I was hosting was under attack... last time I'll ever use drupal. Anyways the ibdata0 was 46GB in size.... which is large for my operation but I still don't see how that would break the database.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot but isn't that solved by setting it back to 0 after it successfully booted? This will fix problems with corrupted log - sure some data in log are lost but normal table data is not corrupted...